# Create apex class from lighting component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I want a custom lighting component with an input field where I provide the class name, and it creates Apex Class with the same name.

**Is possible to create Apex Class with methods from lighting component? If so, how?**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @adirian, I had an idea in my mind if this possible to create an apex class via the lightning component.

Answer (score 1):

It's *possible*, but it's tricky and likely unwise except in highly restricted use cases.

You can programmatically create Apex classes via the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexclass.htm) or the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_classes.htm) (via, perhaps, the [`apex-mdapi`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) wrapper).

[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) is a well-known application that does this.

Note that the user under whose authentication you make the callout must have the appropriate permissions to alter metadata via the API, which exposes a dangerous line of access into your org. Furthermore, in Production, you're responsible for dealing with Apex test coverage in order to perform deployments, which adds another layout of challenge and complexity.